# Adding conditions to an already made regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to add a condition to the already functional regex: `/\/(?=\d*[A-Za-z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{10,20}\b/`, the aforesaid condition being that in order to match, there must be at least 3 capital letters.

Comment: Please _edit_ your question and add sample data.

Answer (score 1):

You could satisfy this requirement by just adding another positive lookahead which asserts three capital letter are present:

```
/\/(?=.*[A-Z].*[A-Z].*[A-Z])(?=\d*[A-Za-z])(?=[a-zA-Z]*\d)[A-Za-z0-9]{10,20}\b/
```

The rest of the logic, in particular the other already existing two lookaheads, might also be able to simplify, given more information about what your regex is supposed to be matching.

Comment: I've checked your answer, in the case of the sequence /sasddasxaDis3fsc|/5MkCDXlmvWYLJGxD||/sknsnsjsjs, it detects sasddasxaDis3fsc despite the lack of presence of the 3 capital characters, any idea why?

Comment: And the regex is supposed to match a 10-20 character string at the end of an URL, the URL has at least 3 capital characters, has a combination of uppercase, lowercase and digits and cannot detect things like <73010825822784709>dDDD2
https://youtube.com/DDausxuxjasus3
https://youtube.com/Baasxjuahauisxh5|

Comment: @ForeverClueless instead of `.*` in the regex above, use `[a-z0-9]*`

Comment: There's multiple line breaks ignores, which one do I replace?